# Can I use CSS to hide the tracking gif used by Google Analytics Mobile?

Tags: css, google-analytics, mobile

I am redesigning my mobile website which uses a 1x1px [Google Analytics for Mobile Websites](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/web/) tracking gif.

The old design displayed the image at the foot of the page, but my new design hides the gif with CSS (`display:none`).

Will this have any affect on the tracking of the site?

****edit****

Whilst I have moved my tracking gif and solved the immediate issue I am hearing [conflicting answers](http://twitter.com/#!/charlesastwood/status/123692057658265600) as to whether an image with `display:none` is, or is not, downloaded.

Can anyone link to any official documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It will still be downloaded and function correctly as a tracking gif, even with `display:none`. You can test this for yourself by adding an `onload` attribute to the image:

`<img src="image.gif" style="display:none" onload="alert('Image loaded!')" />`

This will cause a JavaScript popup to display when the image is downloaded, even though you won't see the image on the page. [Live demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/6Pz55/)

If you make the image's `src` attribute blank, no image is downloaded, so the `onload` event never fires ([live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nVNmU/1/)):

`<img src="" style="display:none" onload="alert('Image loaded!')" />`

The reason that the image is still downloaded is that `display:none` simply "prevents the element from appearing in the formatting structure", in the words of [the W3C spec for the display property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop).

Using `display:none` does not suppress the HTTP request for the image. This fact is depended upon by some JavaScript developers, who create `img` tags styled with`display:none` to pre-cache images before they're ready to be displayed.

Also see the responses to ["Does a element with display:none set in css still get downloaded by the browser?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315192/does-a-element-with-displaynone-set-in-css-still-get-downloaded-by-the-browser) over on Stack Overflow.

As mentioned in [feela's answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20843/can-i-use-css-to-hide-the-tracking-gif-used-by-google-analytics-mobile/20851#20851), though, there's little reason to hide a 1px square tracking gif when you can move it somewhere that won't affect your layout.

Comment: Whether the image will be loaded depends upon the browser's implementation - while it's not so common on desktop browsers now ([not always the case](http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/66942)) there remains the possibility that mobile browser software may demonstrate regressive implementations so testing (or finding others' test results) is always in order.

Comment: @danlefree I agree; it's more future-proof not to hide images if it's essential that they're downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, images which are set to `display: none;` aren't loaded at all – so no tracking takes place. But depends on whether the CSS  is loaded before the markup (e.g. in the `<head>`) or after the markup (which will cause a "loading-flicker"). I don't know about `visibility: hidden;`…

Why are you hiding that tracking-image at all? Just put it somewhere, where nobody will mention it.

Comment: It was affecting layout in its previous position, but I have removed the CSS and moved it now, ta.

Comment: @feeela Are you sure about this? I believe that images are always downloaded even if `display:none` is used, and so it would make little difference where the CSS rule is placed.

Comment: Whoops, you are right. That only counts for the mobile Opera, which parses the CSS on a Opera server. Should I delete the answer?

Comment: @feeela I think the sentence 'Just put it somewhere where nobody will mention it' is good advice. I'd leave your answer as it is (or edit it to remove any errors.)

Comment: If that is correct about mobile Opera then it's worth displaying it for that alone.

Comment: Opera desktop doesn't download `display:none` images either.

Comment: Opera 11.10 (desktop) seems to download `display:none` images OK [ [screenshot](https://img.skitch.com/20111012-db2qm2ue73wh6kwmxia783p8fe.jpg) ]. I'm not able to test earlier versions.